# Run PHP Script using an external Javascript file in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an external Javascript file `initialize_database.js` that uses JQuery to call a PHP script to create a database and some tables. I've tested my PHP script by adding some HTML to it to run it on its own, and it works fine. My HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Test Webpage</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="initialize_database.js"></script>
        <div>
            <h2>Nothing here yet!</h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is `initialize_database.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('testPhp.php' {
        alert('Databases were initialized');
    });
});
```

I'd like to have the Javascript run as soon as the page loads so that the database can be created right away. All files are in the same directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are the commas?

Comment: @HugoWoesthuis I've tried placing the script in the <head> tag. I'll add my php file

Comment: See the answer of deepakkedia.

Answer (score 3):

Comma and function initialization is required after the URL for executing the function correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('testPhp.php', function() {
        alert('Databases were initialized');
    });
});
```

Check this

Comment: @JoeSeph79 don't forget to mark the question as a answer ;). Welcome btw

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code . if you want to run when dom ready then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get('testPhp.php', function() {
    alert('Databases were initialized');
});
});
 if you want to run this full load then use bellow 
 $( window ).load(function() {
   $.get('testPhp.php', function() {
    alert('Databases were initialized');
   });
 });
```